# Accessing a file create throwing error open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in android 11

Tags: android

I created a file using
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images/newImg.jpg");

when I tried to access that file using
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
it throws this error to me
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/Images/ig_1619857233792.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

After that I tried to make file using MediaStore also
and then it throws this error to me
java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/media/external/images/media/109166: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

app is taking "all files access" permission also in android 11 and "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" below android 11

```
public void onDocumentSelectionResult(Intent data) {
    try {
        Uri uri = null;
        fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileType = new ArrayList<>();
        fileName = new ArrayList<>();
        String displayName = null;

        if (data != null) {
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
            String filePath;
            try {
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();

                    String uriString = uri.toString();
                    File myFile = new File(uriString);
                    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                            Cursor cursor = null;
                            try {
                                cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                }
                            } finally {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                            displayName = myFile.getName();
                        }
                    fileName.add(displayName);
                    filePath = uri.getPath();
                    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
                    long file_size = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(sourceFile.length() / 1024));
                    ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
                    String mime = cr.getType(uri);
                    if (mime == null || "".equals(mime)) {
                        mime = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
                    }     
                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            uri = item.getUri();

                            String uriString = uri.toString();
                            File myFile = new File(uriString);

                            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                                Cursor cursor = null;
                                try {
                                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                    }
                                } finally {
                                    cursor.close();
                                }
                            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                                displayName = myFile.getName();
                            }
                            fileName.add(displayName);
                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                                filePath = getPath(ActivityUploadPost.this, uri);
                            } else {
                                filePath = uri.getPath();
                            }
                         //   filePath = getPath(ActivityUploadPost.this, uri);
                            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
                            long file_size = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(sourceFile.length() / 1024));
                            ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
                            String mime = cr.getType(uri);
                        }
                    }
                }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
if(!file.exists()) {
  file.mkdirs();
}
String uriString = (file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ig_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
  out = new FileOutputStream(uriString);
  scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should check first if your directories exists. And if not create them before you try to put a file in them.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, I checked if directory and file exist both exist or not. I found that directory exist and file does not event I am taking "ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION",
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images/newImg.jpg") created a directory but not file in my case

Comment: Please post complete code in your post. I have no idea what you do. Never post code in comments. And post your code in a code block.

Comment: @blackapps, I have post my code as well where I am getting exception

Comment: `if(!file.exists()) {
  file.mkdirs();
}` That should be: `if(!file.exists()) {
 if ( ! file.mkdirs()) return;
}` Do not only return but display a Toast to inform the user about the failure.Please adapt your code. Also here so we see you did it alright.

Comment: @blackapps code is not going inside if condition if(!file.mkdirs()) and also I want to make file and access it so that I can send file to server. Please tell me how to do in android 11

Comment: You did not adapt your code. So what should i tell that you would take?

Comment: @blackapps I have shared the code in which I am taking selected document and getting path from it